# Is the EU Settlement Scheme precluded on the passing of the Withdrawal Agreement?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

The [EU Settlement Scheme](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/718237/EU_Settlement_Scheme_SOI_June_2018.pdf) appears to be the mechanism for EU nationals (and EEA nationals I think) to register with the UK Government so that they have a distinct set of requirements for being permitted to remain resident in the UK (and potentially, ultimately apply for citizenship).

Is this scheme dependent on the passing of the European Union (Withdrawal Agreement) Act, or is it a separate scheme decided unilaterally by the UK that will come into effect even in a no-deal scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The EU Settlement Scheme is a unilateral action on the part of the UK government, and will be open for all EU, EEA and Swiss citizens to apply starting on 30 March.

It is worth noting that the application deadline is sooner if the UK leaves the EU without a deal ([Source: UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/when-to-apply))

Comment: But what about the legislation for it? Has it been passed or is it part of what needs to be passed before March 29th?

Comment: The Home Secretary has the power to change the Immigration Rules under section 3(2) of the Immigration Act, 1971.  No explicit legislation for this scheme is necessary.

Comment: Joe C so they also have the power to revoke that offer at any time? That's pretty scary, especially as the Home Secretary can change on a whim of the PM who is known to be quite xenophobic.

Comment: Parliament does have the power to veto any changes to the Immigration Rules.  But otherwise, yes.